# When using push state redirect in Backbone, how can I keep the "back" button working?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

In a Backbone render, sometimes I need to redirect a page.

For example, let's say someone lands on the "index" page and then clicks "login".
In the login view, I use this code to redirect to register page:

```
Backbone.history.navigate('/register', true);
```

However, when the user clicks back, the user is not taken to "index". Instead, it is taken to "login", which redirects him back to 'register'.

How can I make sure the user goes back to index when he pushes back?

Comment: `window.history.go(-2)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the 'replace' option when you call `.navigate`.

```
Backbone.history.navigate('/register', {replace: true});
```

This is set out [in the documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate): "To update the URL without creating an entry in the browser's history, set the `replace` option to `true`."

(As a side note, I'd be cautious about calling `.navigate` directly on `Backbone.history`; the source code suggests it will work fine, but it's undocumented.)